# Echoing multiple checkbox values In PHP

Tags: php, button, get, forum

I am having trouble using `$_GET` with radio buttons.

```
4th<input type="checkbox" name="date" value="4th">
5th<input type="checkbox" name="date" value="5th">
6th<input type="checkbox" name="date" value="6th">
```

The user chooses what days they are available.  Then I want to echo out what days the user selected:

```
<?php echo "You are available " . $_GET["date"] . "!"; ?>
```

The above code only echos out one.  Not all three.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Change `name="date"` to `name="date[]"`

Answer (score 1):

`checkbox` values are returned in an array as they share the same index, so you need to use `name="date[]"` in your HTML.

If you want to know more, just try to `print_r($_GET['date']);` and see what you get.

And you've tagged your question as `radio` so would like to inform you that `radio` and `checkbox` are 2 different things, `radio` returns single value, where `checkbox` can return multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Name will be an array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="4th" />
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="5th" />
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="6th" />
```

Then get value like this

```
<?php

echo "You are available ";
foreach($_POST["date"] as $value) {
    echo "$value";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each input an id:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="date1" value="4th" />
<input type="checkbox" id="date2" value="5th" />
<input type="checkbox" id="date3" value="6th" />
```

Then echo it like this:

```
$date1 = $_GET["date1"];
$date2 = $_GET["date2"];
$date3 = $_GET["date3"];

<?php echo "You are available " . $date1. ",". $date2. ",". $date3. ",". "!"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Xth<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="Xth">
```

You can  use in php

```
$_POST['date'][0]
$_POST['date'][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use array to get multiple value -

Code:

```
4th<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="4th">
5th<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="5th">
6th<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="6th">

<?php
   $date=$_GET['date'];
   foreach($date as $dt){
     echo "You are available " . $dt . "!<br>";
   }
?>
```

I am not checking above code. I guess it will work.