# How can I see which button has been pressed in php?

Tags: php, database

I'm quite new to php so this might seem very easy. I have a table called 'products' and for each product in that table I want to create a button with the id of that product. I have no problem creating the buttons but I can not see which of the buttons has been pressed.

How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM `products` WHERE subcategory = 'laptop' ORDER BY id desc limit 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$id = mysql_result($query,0);
for($i=1; $i<= $id; $i++){  
    $product2 = R::load('products', $i);
    echo "<input type='submit' name='$product2->id' value='Add to cart'/>";
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: You'll need to show some code. If you're asking on getting some type of notification or writing it to DB, then please include that in your question.

Comment: @ztripez I was not asking you to do my work. I am just asking for an idea, not even for code because I can do that myself and yes I did a lot of research before asking this question.

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753736/php-adding-up-checkboxes there are answers in there you can use. You will need a `foreach` for what you're wanting to do. Plus, see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680250/echoing-multiple-radio-button-values-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks a lot! It works great with the answers from that question.

Comment: You can upvote the answer that you chose in the question/answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will definitely rate it after I get some extra points to my reputation. Thanks a lot :) !

Comment: You're welcome. You should have enough now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

assign a value to the button/input

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="button1" />
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="button2" />
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="button3" />


<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btn'); ?>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" name="btn1" value="button1" />
<input type="submit" name="btn2" value="button2" />
<input type="submit" name="btn3" value="button3" />


<?php if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'btn1')) { echo "button 1 clicked"; } ?>
```